# Which spring transaction manager should I use?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I have a spring mvc 3.1.0.RELEASE webapp which has spring batch 2.1.8.RELEASE built into it. My web application is running on Websphere 6.1 and it is using websphere data sources (for my local environment I am running over tomcat using tomcat data sources).

I am a bit confused about what spring transaction manager I should use. At the moment I have specified a org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager which looks like it is specific to spring batch jobs. But will that transaction manager also work for the rest of my web application? Maybe I need a transaction manager for spring batch and then a transaction manager for the rest of my web application?

I would appreciate some advice. An extract of my Spring config is shown below...

Thanks

```
<beans profile="pre,prod">  



    <bean id="ePosDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/reportingManagerDataSource"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="ePosDataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/reportingManagerDataSource"
        cache="true"
        resource-ref="true"
        lookup-on-startup="false"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>    

    <bean id="custDbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/reportingManagerCustDbDataSource"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>    

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="custDbDataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/reportingManagerCustDbDataSource"
        cache="true"
        resource-ref="true"
        lookup-on-startup="false"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>                            
</beans>

<beans>        
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    </beans>                    
</beans>
```

Comment: For WebSphere, I would think you'd want to use `org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager`. If you don't want to leverage WebSphere's JTA services, then you could probably use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` without any problems. I think either of these could be reused between batch jobs and web app.

Comment: Thanks. You have me curious now of the differences between the two.